# How to get field that made form dirty in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Is there any way to know what field made the form dirty in Angular? I have an "auto save" directive that checks if there was any change inside the form, and saves it accordingly (trough server request), the code is as follows:

```
app.directive 'nxAutoSave', ($timeout) ->
return  {
scope: {
  nxError: '='
  nxAutoSave: '&'
}
require: ["^form"]
link: (scope, element, attrs, ctrls) ->
  dirtyElement = null
  $formCtrl = ctrls[0]
  savePromise = null

  scope.$watch ->
    if $formCtrl.$valid and $formCtrl.$dirty
      $timeout.cancel savePromise if savePromise
      savePromise = $timeout(->
        savePromise = null
        # Still valid?
        if $formCtrl.$valid
          scope.nxAutoSave()
          $formCtrl.$setPristine()
        return
      , 1100)
    return

  scope.$watch 'nxError', (newVal, oldVal) ->
    #???
```

}

The directive watches the nxError (used as a callback) to know if there has been any error sent by the server. Inside the method, I want to display a popover with the error message, but I need to know what element made the form dirty in order to activate my popover...

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Each named input within the form has a dirty state too. If you put a name attribute on the input elements, they will be available on the form for you to check. So if you have a form defined as:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input name="myField" type="text" ng-model="myModel" />
</form>
```

you will, on the scope be able to see:

```
scope.myForm.myField.$dirty;
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks! It's a start, but since it's a directive to be used in any form, I don't know the names of the fields beforehand, so I can't call "scope.myForm.myField.$dirty"...